# Статистика в игре

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток,делаю игру на C# Win Forms.Необходимо сделать статистику по игрокам и при запуске игры,чтобы можно было, либо добавлять нового игрока, либо выбирать из уже созданных записей.Как реализовать?Нашел базу данных DataGridWiew,но это немного не то,что нужно.Создавать новую структуру для каждого игрока и хранить в файле?Тогда как сделать выбор игрока(в выпадающем меню,например)помогите пожалуйста,в каком направлении двигаться,нет идей вообще.Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1. Заведите структуру данных, описывающую одного игрока. Внутри неё храните всю относящуюся к игроку статистику. Не забудьте реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
2. Заведите список таких структур. Для WinForms наверное лучше подойдёт `BindingList`.
3. При окончании работы программы сериализуйте список на диск (например, через Settings, или вручную). При повторном запуске десериализуйте с диска.
4. Отображать список можно при помощи чего угодно, например, через `ListBox`.

Comment: Спасибо большое,а выбор игрока как реализовать,не подскажите?

Comment: @МаксимУстелемов: Если вы используете `ListBox`, то можно через [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).